# matlplotlib pdf savefig: markers change

Tags: python, matplotlib

Under windows matplotlib changes the linewidth of white, filled markers when saving as pdf. Saving as PNG works fine. I am using anaconda with python3.3 and matplotlib 1.3.1

I found a closed thread on github: [Open markers incorrect in PDF output](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1410/) as well as this SO question [matplotlib linewidth when saving a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093408/matplotlib-linewidth-when-saving-a-pdf).

Under Linux, using eps or pdf makes no difference.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue ?

The circular markers are cutted at the outside border like masked with a white rectangle.

CODE:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1.5,1.5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.plot([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],'wo')
fig.savefig('testfig.pdf',bbox_inches='tight', format='pdf')
plt.show()
```

EDITED:
Damn. It is a FoxitReader related issue. With Sumatra PDF everything is fine.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code example?  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: should i write a bug report ?

Comment: Is there anyway you can test on the master branch on windows? and are you sure you are using the same version of mpl on both linux and windows?

Comment: I am using python3-matplotlib from Debian jessie. It is 1.3.1-1 .

Comment: I do not know anything about a master branch in windows but i tested it with python2.7 and matplotlib 1.3.1 . All installed with anacondas apkg.Here is a link with the output pdf:
https://bokubox.boku.ac.at/#f170d5bf871729a039779c4a2be2a345

Comment: Please make a bug report.  Make clear that this looks like a windows-specific bug.